# Facebook login: Check authentication at every page?

Tags: php, facebook, session

I'm following this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Everything is working fine with regards to the login. What I don't understand is how I handle 'sessions':

- I guess FB.getLoginStatus is used instead of sessions?
- I have to check FB.getLoginStatus 36 every time the user enters a new page in my website. Does that mean I have to initialize the JavaScript SDK for every page? That's 50 lines of code for every page just to check the login status.

I am using PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, and HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess FB.getLoginStatus is used instead of sessions?

`FB.getLoginStatus` is used to help you optimize your visitors experience based on their login status and hence it's not a replacement of "*sessions*".

> I have to check FB.getLoginStatus everytime the user enters a new page
>   in my website. Does that mean i have to initialize the JavaScript SDK
>   for every page? Thats 50 lines of code for every page just to check
>   the login status...

Well, initializing the Javascript SDK is something *you have* to do if you wish to use the SDK. Now I don't see anything wrong with the *numbers of lines of code*, as Facebook already loads the SDK asynchronously and hence it won't block your page resources.

And for your first point, you don't have to call `FB.getLoginStatus` every time on page load and Facebook already states this in the related [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/):

> While you can call `FB.getLoginStatus` any time (for example, when the
>   user tries to take a social action), most social apps need to know the
>   user's status as soon as possible after the page loads. In this case,
>   rather than calling `FB.getLoginStatus` explicitly, it is possible to
>   check the user's status by setting `status: true` when you call `FB.init`.
>
> To receive the response of this call, you must subscribe to the
>   `auth.statusChange` event. The response object passed by this event is
>   identical to that which would be returned by calling `FB.getLoginStatus`
>   explicitly.

---

Now one thing that you might have missed, is the [PHP-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/):

> The Facebook SDK for PHP can work in conjunction with the Facebook SDK
>   for Javascript to provide seamless session management across both the
>   client and server-sides of an app.

This would make your life easier as you would have an idea of the user status upon (before) loading the page and hence customize the user experience accordingly and then wait for any status change triggered by the Javascript SDK.

Comment: Thanks. Just to get my head around this: The php sdk reads the cookie which was set by the javascript sdk ? Then to get current status, i just check the cookie throughout my site?

Comment: Yes, the PHP-SDK and the JS-SDK share the same cookie names and hence this is way they play nicely together. Now to check the "*current status*" (while serving the page), you could just use `$facebook->getUser()` and always make use of the JS-SDK event listeners for any change that may happen while the user is on page.

Comment: You could always go through the SDK to understand how it operates, for example this [function](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L659).

Answer (score 0):

From the Facebook Developers area it seems they have a section on how to login without calling their Javascript SDK.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-without-js-sdk/

The user will have an API access token which can be used for further requests.

I hope that helps.