# Facebook php-sdk/js-sdk: Cookie/Session management

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook login: Check authentication at every page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420639/facebook-login-check-authentication-at-every-page)

I'm following these guides:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

So, the cookie is set in the FB.init() js function, but i don't understand:

- how PHP SDK reads the cookie? do i have to use getUser()? This is abit unclear in the guide, i think.
- what do i include in every page of my site to check login status?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example included in SDK. Here is the URL
[Facebook PHP SDK example with JS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php)